# How to validate the key and value not to be empty in array?

Tags: node.js, angular

Parameter validation
I want to ensure that the array must not be empty in any cost so that i want to validate the array

imgList= [
{
"fileType": "png",
"fileContent": "base64"
},
{
"fileType": "png",
"fileContent": "base64"
}
]
I want to validate both key and value is present or not (it should not be empty)

```
eg: filetype is missing
   {
    
      "fileContent": "base64"
    },
eg2: value is missing
    {
      "fileType": "",
      "fileContent": "base64"
    },
```

Code which i have tired is

```
body.imgList.forEach((item) => {
      var key,
        count = 0;
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key) && !!value) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      var objectLenght = count;
      if (objectLenght != 2) {
        return cb({"status_code":400,"status":"Pass all the required fields"});
      }   
    });
```

When I try this worked is died and image are uploaded with out type in s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works, you can use isOkay function to verify if the array is valid

```js
const isOkay = (arr)=> {
let okay = true;
for(let entry of arr){
  if(!entry.hasOwnProperty('fileType') || !entry['fileType'] || !entry.hasOwnProperty('fileContent') || !entry['fileContent']){
    okay = false; 
    break;
  }
}
return okay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's `truthy` / `falsy` system takes care of this for you. If the key does not exist you will get `undefined` when attempting to access it, which is `falsy`. An empty string is also a `falsy` value.

```js
function validate(data) {
  if (!data || !data.length) return false;
  for (const item of data) {
    if (!item || !item.fileType || !item.fileContent) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

if (validate(body.imgList)) return cb({ status_code: 400, status: 'Pass all the required fields' });;
```

More info on `falsy`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy